# find Max value from ObservableCollection of type KeyPair

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I want to find Max Value from a ObsevableCollection Of type KeyPair... this is my KeyPair class

```
    public class KeyPairs : ViewModelBase
    {
    private string _key;
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return _key;
        }
        set
        {
            _key = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Key);
        }
    }

    private double _value;
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I have  used

```
  var max = newCriteria.KeyValue.Max(values => values.Value);"
```

but it is not showing any result.??

Comment: could  you  post  how KeyValue is defined in NewCriteria

Comment: why create a class? why not use what already exists? new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();

Comment: Assuming that `KeyValue` is defined as `ObservableCollection<KeyPairs>`, your code should return the maximum `Value`...

Answer (score 1):

so assume you have a list of KeyPair

```
var list = new List<KeyPair>();

// assign the data to the list
// here...

// get max value from the list
var max = list.Max(d => d.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is maybe in your KeyValue property.
The following snippet works.

```
public class KeyPairs
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

var keyValuePairs = new List<KeyPairs>
{
    new KeyPairs {Key = "a", Value = 30},
    new KeyPairs {Key = "b", Value = 20}
};

double max = keyValuePairs.Max(pairs => pairs.Value);
```

Best of luck ;-)